# Proving a vector bisect two other vectors

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

How can I prove the vector:
$$
\vec{w}=|\vec{u}|\vec{v} + |\vec{v}| \vec{u}
$$
bisects the angle between the vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ ?

I have trying using the scalar product, but it does not help me. Thanks!

Comment: How have you tried using the scalar product? (It can tell you the angle between any pair of vectors.)

Comment: $cos(\theta_{w,u})=\frac{u\cdot w}{|u||w|}$, what does this give me?

Comment: you can write down what $u\cdot w$ is in terms of $u$ and $v$: $u\cdot w = |u|u\cdot v + |v|u\cdot v = u\cdot v(|u| + |v|)$...

Comment: When you finish the algebra you can post an answer to your own question.  I hope that happens before someone comes along and does it for you.

Comment: OK. after some algebra I obtain
$\frac{cos(\theta_{w,v})}{|v|}=\frac{cos(\theta_{w,u})}{|u|}$. Shouldn't I get an equality without a denominator?

Comment: By the way, @JohnMartin: I think you have a mistake- $u\cdot w = |u|u\cdot v + |v|u\cdot u = $ and not what you wrote. Am I right? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Ah, haha woops. You are right yes! I was just making sure you were paying attention ;)

Comment: So, have you got any idea about how I should solve this one?

Comment: @JohnMartin ? :(

Comment: @bbbburgers I posted an answer. Let me know if you need firther clarification. I am not sure how far along you are in your math career...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to compute $\theta_{u,w}$, and we know that $\cos\theta_{u,w} = \frac{u\cdot w}{|u||w|}$. Let's compute $u\cdot w$ in terms of $u$ and $v$:
\begin{align*}
    u\cdot w &= |u|u\cdot v + |v|u\cdot u\\
             &= |u|^2|v|\cos\theta_{u,v} + |u|^2|v|\\
             &= |u|^2|v|(1 + \cos\theta_{u,v})
\end{align*}

Then, we can also compute
    $$ |w| = \sqrt{w\cdot w} = \sqrt{2}|u||v|\sqrt{1+\cos\theta_{u,v}}.$$
From this we then have
    \begin{align*}
     \cos\theta_{u,w} &= \frac{u\cdot w}{|u||w|}\\
                    & = \frac{|u|^2|v|(1 + \cos\theta_{u,v})}{\sqrt{2}|u|^2|v|\sqrt{1+\cos\theta_{u,v}}}\\
               &= \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta_{u,v}}{2}}
\end{align*}
Thus $\theta_{u,w} = \theta_{u,v}/2$ by the half angle formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I completely missed the $|w|$ in the denominator. Very nice solution and explanation! THanks